# Selection using multiple wilcards (more than 2)

Tags: jquery

I want to select all the elements which `id` start with:

`billServicesPerformed`

and finish with

`quantity` or `unitPrice`

I have tried with this:

```
$(document).on('change key paste keyup', '[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="quantity"][id$="unitPrice"]', function() {
```

but it is not working..

Comment: Your question says `billServicesPerformed`, but your selector is `bill_servicesPerformed`, is there an underscore?

Comment: It's not going to.  You are matching things where the ID ends with _both_ quantity _and_ unitPrice (not either or)!  Nothing will ever match that.

Comment: Best bet might be to define a named function to be the callback and asign it to two seperate `.on()` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to select an element with an `id` starting with `bill_servicesPerformed` and ending with `quantity` **and** `unitPrice`. That clearly doesn't work because the element can't end with both of those strings.

You need to group the selectors with a comma in order to select an element that ends in `quantity` **or** `unitPrice`, therefore you could use the following selectors:

```
[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="quantity"],
[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="unitPrice"]
```

And your event listener would be:

```
$(document).on('change key paste keyup', '[id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="quantity"], [id^="bill_servicesPerformed"][id$="unitPrice"]', function() {});
```

Alternatively, you could also use a basic regular expression:

```
var $elements = $('[id]').filter(function () {
  return this.id.match(/^bill_servicesPerformed.*(?:quantity|unitPrice)$/);
});
```